Powershell closure for .Where() in a string variable
I have a Generic List of hash tables derived from Uninstall keys in the registry, which I need to search. Each list member is an ordered dictionary containing these keys. The actual value of each key is defined separately since some are values direct from the registry and some are calculated.
[Ordered]@{
        displayName = 'DisplayName'
        displayVersion = 'DisplayVersion'
        installSource = 'InstallSource'
        publisher = 'Publisher'
        quietUninstallString = 'QuietUninstallString'
        uninstallParam = 'UninstallParam'
        uninstallPath = 'UninstallPath'
        uninstallString = 'UninstallString'
        installDate = 'InstallDate'
        keyID = '$keyID'
        keyName = '$keyName'
        keyGUID = '$keyGUID'
        keyPath = '$keyPath'
        architecture = '$architecture'
    } 

Once I have this collection in a variable $rawUninstallKeys I need to search it, and the search is convoluted because Autodesk tends to have multiple uninstall keys with the same or similar data, but only one will work. For example there will be a GUID key with a DisplayName of Autodesk Revit 2025 that provides a uninstall string that actually works and another GUID with a DisplayName of Revit 2025 that does nothing. So to extract the correct uninstallString I need to search for a key that matches the first pattern AND has a second key that matches the second pattern. And there are actually a ton of variations because Autodesk just sucks at any kind of consistency.
So, I have this working now where I just do a foreach on the raw keys looking for the first pattern, and if I find it I derive the second pattern (in this case I replace 'Autodesk ' with $null) and then search with another foreach. And it does work, but dear god it's slow.
So, I want to try using the .Where() method on the list to get the .NET optimization. But that means building a collection of closures to apply.
So, this will work
$rawUninstallKeys.Where({$_.publisher -like "Autodesk*"})

but I am struggling with how to get the closure into a variable that still allows $_ to expand appropriately. This is further complicated by the fact that my closure might simply be {$_.DisplayName} when I just need to see if that value exists at all, or {-not $_.DisplayName} when I only want a key that doesn't contain that property, or the first example where I need to compare the properties value to another value, which may be a wildcard.
Effectively what I kind of need to do is expand the variable in the closure string within the .Where(), but this doesn't work
.Where({$($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($closure))})


Foreach($Item in $Collection){ If( ) { } } is actually faster than .Where() in most situations, perhaps that might help?

@sirtao that has not been my experience. I found .Where() to be faster than a loop which was itself faster (usually a lot faster) than anything using the pipeline. My plan is to profile performance here before I implement anything in production code, but just getting the closure to work has been a challenge.

Can you show the code that does the search over the top-level list? I’m having trouble visualising it from the description… (if it’s massive due to lots of variations in the patterns maybe slim it down to a representative example). Also, are you sure their performance issue is in the search over the list , and not in the part that scrapes the registry to build the list of hashtables in the first place?

@ mclayton A simplified version would be that this works $rawUninstallKeys.Where({$_.publisher -like "Autodesk*"}). But if I put the closure in a variable, either with the {} in the closure or in the call, as here $closureString = '$_.publisher -like "Autodesk*"'; $rawUninstallKeys.Where({$closureString}) doesn't filter anything.

Eventually I will want to build multiple closures with different properties and values, but just this simplified version has me banging my head.

FWIW, if the {} is in the variable, it doesn't seem like it's acting like a closure and throws, while when it's in the call, then the variable just evaluates to true because it's not nil, so no filtering but no errors. So maybe this is just a place where a closure can't be used. :(

In your last example you are writing it wrong: $Closure = { $_.Publisher -like 'Autodesk*' };  $rawUninstallKeys.Where($Closure)

.Where is actually one of the slowest ways to filter a collection but also it's unclear to me why not enumerate the collection once using an if condition with $_.Publisher -like 'Autodesk*' -and -not $_.Contains('DisplayName')

So here are my results of a first performance test. I run each kind of search 3 times, interleaved. The int at the end of each line is the .Count. According to this the two approaches are actually pretty similar, with .Where() having the fastest time and foreach the slowest, but not by much.
[0:0:0.464] : Get all uninstall keys 159
[0:0:0.271] : .Where() MsiExec /X 92
[0:0:0.279] : foreach MsiExec /X 92
[0:0:0.270] : .Where() MsiExec /X 92
[0:0:0.285] : foreach MsiExec /X 92
[0:0:0.273] : .Where() MsiExec /X 92
[0:0:0.272] : foreach MsiExec /X 92

One thing I realize I have never been doing is removing the found items. The really long executions are when finding all installed programs based on a pattern of data (to build an appropriate uninstall). I wonder if removing everything that has been accounted for so the list gets smaller will help, or if the time to do the remove makes it a wash. More to test!

Per @sirtao's comment, you don't need to stringify and then de-stringify your scriptblock - you can just pass it directly to .Where():
Let's set up some test data:
$rawUninstallKeys = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.IDictionary]]::new()

$rawUninstallKeys.Add(
    [ordered] @{
        publisher   = "Autodesk Revit 2025"
    }
)

$rawUninstallKeys.Add(
    [ordered] @{
        displayname = "displayname"
        publisher   = "Revit 2025"
    }
)

and then if you've got a series of filters you want to apply:
$filters = @(
    { $_.Publisher -like 'Autodesk*' },
    { $_.DisplayName }
)

you can just do this:
foreach( $filter in $filters )
{
    write-host "testing for $filter"
    $rawUninstallKeys.Where($filter) | ft | out-string
}

which gives the output:
testing for  $_.Publisher -like 'Autodesk*'

Name                           Value
----                           -----
publisher                      Autodesk Revit 2025

testing for  $_.DisplayName

Name                           Value
----                           -----
displayname                    displayname
publisher                      Revit 2025

You can extend this to just run the filters in order until you find the first one that returns a result, if that's what you need...

Woot! to Clayton & Sirtao. Next step is figuring out how to get properties, operators and values out of XML into a series of closures to apply in a loop. And then verify that this really is faster. :)

@Gordon - if you don't mind a bit of code injection vulnerability you can just store the powershell code - e.g. <filter>$_.Publisher -like 'Autodesk*'</filter> and then convert it to a scriptblock inside the foreach: foreach( $filter in $filters ) { $sb = [scriptblock]::Create($filter); $rawUninstallKeys.Where($sb) | ft | out-string, but bear in mind you'd be executing arbitrary code stored in the xml (e.g. <filter>Format-Volume -DriveLetter C</filter> :-S
